# Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m' in react native

Tags: java, react-native

I'm facing this issue while running react native.

```
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

My system java version is ,

```
Java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Without changing the version How do I run the react native app

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm running into this now.

Comment: Yes , Jdk 17 had some problem and I downgraded the jdk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m' and Could not create the Java Virtual Machine when running React Native Apps (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545053/unrecognized-vm-option-maxpermsize-512m-and-could-not-create-the-java-virtual)